# Selecting one kubernetes pod among a set of copies to perform a task

Tags: kubernetes, apache-zookeeper

I have a java application that runs inside a Kubernetes pod.

The application performs several tasks (`taskA`, `taskB`, etc.).  The application supports running multiple instances in different pods.  All the pods are doing the same tasks.

However, there is a task that should only be done by only one of the pods (e.g. `taskA` should only run in one of the pods).  And if the pod that is performing the specific task dies, one of the other nodes should start doing that task (passive node, with regards to `taskA`, takes over).

Is there some support for this feature in k8s, or do I need use some other service (e.g. zookeeper)?

Comment: what is a task in your case? batch job? serving some specific endpoint? other?

Answer (score 1):

Kubernetes doesn't know what's running inside your pods or what's inside your requests.  There's (almost) no direct support for what you're suggesting.

The more general topic you might look up is *leader election*.  In your example, the cluster leader is the only one who can perform the `taskA`.  [ZooKeeper](http://zookeeper.apache.org) is popularly used for this; there's a newer algorithm called [Raft](https://raft.github.io) that can work too.  You'd have to write support for this into your application.

The closest thing in Kubernetes is a [StatefulSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/).  The helpful feature of a StatefulSet is that [its replicas are numbered starting from 0](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/#pod-identity), so a pod can look at its own hostname and figure out which one it is.  If a lower-number pod fails then Kubernetes will restart it with the same identity.  You could set the rule that only pod 0 could perform `taskA`, which in practice might meet your requirements.

Comment: Using StatefulSet sounds promising. Assume Replica0 is responsible for running "task0".  Replica0 restarts and takes too long to come back online.  In this case, I want Replica1 to take over "taskA".  And later on when Replica0 is back online, there are two options, IMO:
- Replica0 should recognize that Replica1 has taken over "taskA", so it does not do "taskA".
- Replica1 realizes that Replica0 is back online, and stops doing "taskA", and by some mechanism synchronizes with Replica0, at which point Replica0 starts doing "taskA".  Thoughts?

Comment: If ReplicaN needs to observe the status of all of the preceding replicas to decide whether it needs to be the leader, you probably haven't gained anything over using a prebuilt Raft library.  If you can't use the "Replica0 is the master or nobody is" shortcut then I probably wouldn't try to use a StatefulSet.

Comment: I also don't know what would happen in the case of network partitions or errors.  Say something goes wrong and Replica0 accepts inbound connections, but fails to write responses; could Replica1 decide Replica0 is offline, and both decide they're the masters?

Comment: Ah, case of split brain.  To keep it simple, I am going going with your suggestion, setting rule that Replica0 will always perform TaskA, always be the master.  This will suffice my needs.  Thank you very much for your suggestions and advise, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

After researching David's answer, I found the Kubernetes blog recommends a way to do leader election:

https://kubernetes.io/blog/2016/01/simple-leader-election-with-kubernetes/

Newer articles have come out since then with improvements to that algorithm but they are still based on the original technique, according to this article:

https://medium.com/hybrid-cloud-hobbyist/leader-election-architecture-kubernetes-32600da81e3c

It looks like you'll have to copy a bit of code or add in a new external dependency for this.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Malgorzata's answer, you may be able to have a separate single-instance application launch a task by making an HTTP request to your main app, or by publishing a message to a message queue system like Kafka, hopefully without needing to duplicate or share too much code/configuration with your main app. May be some set up costs to deploy it alongside the main app too.

In my case I needed one task to scan an FTP directory and put newly found filenames into Kafka, and I realized my company supported Confluent Kafka connectors so I was able to just use that instead.

Just giving this as an alternative to leader election. Leader election seems more robust if you're willing to implement it -- no need for a separate component that may logically belong in the main app, and has a single pod which can go down and take a long time to restart, ie. single point of failure.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I understand I think you should use [ReplicaSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/).

You should create two ReplicaSet, first one for **task A**, and second one for **task B**.

> A ReplicaSet is defined with fields, including a selector that
>   specifies how to identify Pods it can acquire, a number of replicas
>   indicating how many Pods it should be maintaining, and a pod template
>   specifying the data of new Pods it should create to meet the number of
>   replicas criteria. A ReplicaSet then fulfills its purpose by creating
>   and deleting Pods as needed to reach the desired number. When a
>   ReplicaSet needs to create new Pods, it uses its Pod template.
>
> The link a ReplicaSet has to its Pods is via the Pods’
>   metadata.ownerReferences field, which specifies what resource the
>   current object is owned by. All Pods acquired by a ReplicaSet have
>   their owning ReplicaSet’s identifying information within their
>   ownerReferences field. It’s through this link that the ReplicaSet
>   knows of the state of the Pods it is maintaining and plans
>   accordingly.
>
> A ReplicaSet identifies new Pods to acquire by using its selector. If
>   there is a Pod that has no OwnerReference or the OwnerReference is not
>   a Controller and it matches a ReplicaSet’s selector, it will be
>   immediately acquired by said ReplicaSet.

A ReplicaSet is responsible for running specified number of pod replicas at any given time.

Here is simple yaml configuration file for ReplicaSet:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: ReplicaSet
metadata:
  name: example
  labels:
    app: guestbook
    tier: eg
spec:
  replicas: 1 #provided appreciated amount of replicas
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      tier: eg
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        tier: eg
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: php
        image: gcr.io/google_samples/gb-frontend:v3
```

Comment: Does it help ? Would you consider upvote/accept it, it will be useful for community.